# Disable browser caching for Google Chrome for a single ASP.NET web form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

I have tried the following in the page_load event with no luck. (Note: The page language is VB)

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1))
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(False)    
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)       
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE ADDED SOME CODE TO REMOVE cache from browser.I page load event add

```
                List<string> keys = new List<string>();
                IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
                    Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
```

in vb.net

```
        Dim keys As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim enumerator As IDictionaryEnumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator()
        While enumerator.MoveNext()
            keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString())
        End While
        For i = 0 To keys.Count - 1
            Cache.Remove(keys(i))
        Next i
```